# How can I get input filename from JavaScript to python?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to use filename variable (i.e filename of input file by user) in a python code .

javascript:

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const upload = require('express-fileupload')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()

app.use(upload())


app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

})

app.post('/', (req,res)=> {
    if(req.files){
        console.log(req.files)
        var file = req.files.file
        var filename = file.name
        console.log(filename)
        

        file.mv(filename,function (err){
            if (err){
                res.send(err)}
            
        })
    }
})
```

From the above javascript code I want to get the filename and use the variable value in my python code (like I am using the variable to print)
python:

```
print(filename)
```

Comment: How is Python involved here?  This is a node.js app server, right?

Comment: yes actually , scenario is like we are running a node js server and we will get an input file from  user and from that I want to use filename  in my python script

Comment: Are you expecting the node.js server to launch your Python script?  You still haven't said how they are connected.

Comment: we are getting file as an input and the name of file is stored in Javascript  . we want to use that name in python script (python script is external) which is not connected with server.

Comment: Then your node.js code can use `child_process.exec` to start an external process, and pass the file name as a command line parameter.  Right?